# Cookies get automatically deleted on refresh after an ajax request

Tags: php, http, cookies

I have a webpage that has a login system. It has an `onsubmit='return login()'` attribute.

In the **login** function, I send an ajax request to the file `login.inc.php` that sets a cookie named `EQ` and outputs a response as true or false. And now problem occurs.

When I check cookies on the website, it contains the `EQ` cookie, but if I refresh the page, it automatically deletes the cookie.

What is the solution and why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share the code setting the cookie?

Comment: thanks but i have got the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Please set the cookies with domain name.

```
setcookie('EQ',"demo",strtotime( '+2 days' ),"/",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Comment: can you please explain why i have to mention the domain!